# How do I access TCP connection?

Tags: tcp

I am extremely new with networking and am learning about the TCP Layer; I'm writing software thats going to speak with a tcp server.

I tried googling: `tcp schema` and `tcp protocol` but i cannot find how i can communicate with a tcp server.

is it something like `tcp://127.0.0.1:8083`

i apologize if this is extremely easy but like i said im new to networking so i really dont know how i am going to communicate my software with the tcp server.

i tried `curl tcp://127.0.0.1:8083` but that failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP is a transport layer protocol, something like `curl` operates on application layer protocols (e.g., HTTP). Look up the OSI 7-layer model to learn more about the specifics as this question is very broad.